# make sure that the closure of $A = \{ f^j(a_k) : 0 ≤ j < k \,\,\,\, , k ≥ 1 \}$ is countable.

Tags: general-topology

If $f: [0,1] \rightarrow[0,1]$ defined by $f(x)= 10x- \lfloor 10x \rfloor$ and  $a_k = 1/(10^k − 1)$. make sure that the closure of $A = \{ f^j(a_k) : 0 ≤ j < k \,\,\,\, , k ≥ 1 \}$ is countable. 
I do not know how to do it. Someone can help

Comment: This problem involves operations that look simpler if the numbers involved are written in decimal notation. This is, as a (possibly infinite) sum of powers of $10$. Observe that $f(x)$ all it does is to shift the fractional part to the left (and drop the integer part in the case of $x=1$). Also write $a_k$ in decimal notation $a_k=\frac{1}{10^k}\frac{1}{1-1/10^k}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}10^{kn}$. This is, the decimal expansion has repeated 1s separated by $k$ zeros.